# Varnish Running VCC-compiler failed on purge

Tags: varnish

I've been following [this guide](http://www.ewanleith.com/blog/900/10-million-hits-a-day-with-wordpress-using-a-15-server) which uses this [default.vcl](https://github.com/ewanleith/Wordpress-Server-Configuration-Files/blob/master/default.vcl). However, when starting Varnish I get the following error:

```
 * Starting HTTP accelerator                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           [fail] 
storage_malloc: max size 1024 MB.
Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected '(' got ';'
(program line 341), at
(input Line 43 Pos 22)
                purge;
---------------------#
Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1
VCL compilation failed
```

Which means that there is something wrong with purge here:

```
sub vcl_hit {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                purge;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}
```

I don't see anything wrong, can someone explain?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the complete config file?

Comment: Hi Paul, you can find it here: https://github.com/ewanleith/Wordpress-Server-Configuration-Files/blob/master/default.vcl

Comment: What version of Varnish are you running (`varnishd -V`)? `purge` is only available in Varnish 3. In Varnish 2.x the equivalent was `set obj.ttl = 0s;`

Comment: Ah, that was it, I installed Varnish 3 from https://www.varnish-cache.org/installation/ubuntu now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code block you have used is perfectly valid - in fact I use a nearly identical one with my Varnish setup (and I presume many others do as well).

As the error suggests there is a problem with `purge`. Since `purge` was only introduced in Varnish 3.x, if you are using a prior version of Varnish (2.x) the command will be unrecognised, and compilation will fail. You can determine your version of Varnish by running `varnishd -V`.

If you are using a previous version of Varnish, and are unable to upgrade, the equivalent command is `set obj.ttl = 0s;`.

Varnish maintains up-to-date repositories for Ubuntu/Debian and RHEL/CentOS distributions on their [download page](https://www.varnish-cache.org/releases/varnish-cache-3.0.2).